# HTML Element with React variable does not display ASCII

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ascii

I have a custom title being received and set in a JS variable. But the output shows the ASCII code instead of the symbol. Here is a simple example of the render function:

```
render() {
   var title = "My Title&#8482;"
   return <div>{title}</div>;
}
```

And the output is

> My Title`&#8482;`

rather than

> My Title™

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert html from a string, even if it's not a tag.

So you have two easy solutions to fix this.

First you can wrap this element in a tag and insert it afterwards:

```
var title = ["My Title", <span>&#8482</span>]
```

Second, you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) even though it's not recommended because, well, it's dangerous.

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: title}}></div>
```

For completeness, @Tom Fenech showed two other elegant solutions in his answer.

Full working code:

```js
var Example = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
     var listTitle = ["My Title", <span>&#8482;</span>]
     var dangerousTitle = "My other Title&#8482;";
     return <div>
         {listTitle}<br/>
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: dangerousTitle}}></div>
     </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include a ™ symbol in a string, then either use the character itself directly, or refer to it using `\u2122` (the unicode code point).

As long as your files are saved and served up in the correct encoding, then you shouldn't have a problem with either approach.

```js
function testComponent() {
    return React.DOM.div(null,
        React.DOM.h3(null, "My Title™"),
        React.DOM.h3(null, "My Title\u2122"));
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(testComponent), 
    document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thx for adding this as well. I think it'll be my best option as the title could have multiple ascii symbols. So this would help me avoid using dangeriouslySetInnerHTML